# Disable session timeout in ksh shell / Korn shell

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I want to keep the session running in PuTTY.

`unset TMOUT` works for Bash but it doesn't work for `ksh`/Korn shell.

What is an alternative command for `unset TMOUT` in `ksh`?

Comment: try `export TMOUT=0`

Comment: @Bart export TMOUT=0 is not working . its timing out with -  -ksh: timed out waiting for input

Comment: just to add: We are using ksh93 version

Comment: What does `typeset -p TMOUT` output?  If the variable is declared as read only (`-r` in the output of that command), then you can't change it or unset it.

Comment: @Kusalananda the output of above command is empty (ie: no output) .I dont think its readonly.

Comment: Is it an ordinary shell session, or is the session running some script (i.e. a possibly interactive script in a non-interactive shell session)?

Comment: @Kusalananda its a ordinary ksh session, just wanted its session to keepalive .'unset TMOUT' worked for bash shell but its not working in ksh.

Comment: It does not work because it's obviously not used for timing out the session (as it is not set).  The timing out of the session is done using some other means. Is the timeout happening only after a certain time of _inactivity_, or does it always happen after some time regardless of whether you've used the shell or not?

Comment: @Kusalananda under /etc we have TMOUT set as 15 mins .Even if i do echo $TMOUT it shows 900. if i do unset TMOUT under bash shell it works but if do the same under ksh it does not work.Looking for some alternative in ksh93 to disable this timeout option

Comment: If `TMOUT` is set, then `typeset -p TMOUT` should have printed _something_.

Comment: @Kusalananda Not sure why its not showing but echo $TMOUT is showing 900 sec .